# Subroutine in Fortran don't recognize type

Tags: types, fortran, subroutine

I have the following code

```
module oc_tree

    type star
        integer :: id
        real(8) :: v(3)=0, r(3)=0
    end type

    type node
        real(8) :: corners(3,2)
        type(node), dimension(:), pointer :: child_nodes
        type(node), pointer :: father
        type(star), allocatable :: stars_in(:)
        real(8) :: tot_mass, center_mass(3)
        integer :: id
    end type node


    contains

    subroutine head_node(n2,m, stars, node1)
        real(8), intent(IN) ::m
        integer, intent(IN) :: n2
        type(star), allocatable, dimension(:), intent(in) :: stars
        real(8), parameter :: parsec = 3.085677581d16, d = 6661d3*parsec
        integer :: i

        type(node), intent(OUT) :: node1

        procedure...

    end subroutine head_node

   recursive subroutine tree(m, node1)
        type(node), intent(inout), target :: node1
        integer :: i, n, j, last_id
        real(8) :: c(3,2), r1(3)
        type(node), pointer :: node

        node => node1


        call child_cubes(node)

        procedure...

        end  subroutine tree

        subroutine child_cubes(node)
            type(node), intent(inout), target :: node
            real(8) :: x_mid, y_mid, z_mid, c(3,2)
            integer :: i

         procedure

        end subroutine child_cubes



end module oc_tree
```

For some reason in the subroutine "child_cubes" the compiler say's

> "/home/avner/Dropbox/final project/grav/main.f95|176|Error: Derived
>   type ‘node’  is being used before it is defined"

although in the two first subroutine he doesn't have a problem.I don't understand the difference between the two first subroutines and this one, any idea?

Comment: Personally I don't quite believe that that error message came from the code posted.  I think a [mcve] is required.

Comment: One obvious difference between the subroutines is that the first two don't have a dummy argument called the same as the type required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to compile with gfortran 4.8.5, the compiler throws the following informative error on line 37

```
type(node), pointer :: node
                           1   2
Error: The type 'node' cannot be host associated at (1) because it is
       blocked by an incompatible object of the same name declared at (2)
```

in addition to the error at line 49

```
type(node), intent(inout), target :: node
          1
 Error: Derived type 'node' at (1) is being used before it is defined
```

So the problem is, that the both the dummy argument of the `subroutine child_cubes` as well as the internal pointer variable of the `subroutine tree` have the same name (`node`) as the type and thus shadow the type. Changing these names to `node2` or something fixes this issue (in fact, the intel compiler is even fine with the internal pointer variable having the same name as the type, as long as you rename the dummy variable of `subroutine child_cubes`, so which subroutines cause trouble is compiler dependent).

Comment: The rules for this are in section 16.3.1 (Classes of local identifiers) in the F2008 standard:
"Within its scope, a local identifier of one class shall not be the same as another local identifier of the same class, except that a generic name may be the same as the name of a procedure as explained in 12.4.3.4 or the same as the name of a derived type (4.5.10). A local identifier of one class may be the same as a local identifier of another class."
Named variables and derived types are in the same class.

Comment: I reported to Intel the failure to diagnose the error in "tree", issue ID 03510955. I also remarked that Intel Fortran's error message for "child_cubes" was not very helpful.